# How do I save multiple django models in a single transaction?

Tags: django, django-models

In my view, I am saving data in multiple models:

```
def myview(request):
    #do some processing
    model1.save()
    model2.save()
```

How do I ensure that there is a rollback of `model1.save()` in case `model2.save()` raises an error? Or how do I commit only after both the models are successfully saved?

In other words, "only save model1 and model2 if both save() are successful", or "perform both saves inside a transaction".

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use an [atomic transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic):

> Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. atomic allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the database is guaranteed. **If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back.**

Examples:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    model1.save()
    model2.save()
```

and

```
from django.db import transaction, IntegrityError

try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        model1.save()
        model2.save()
except IntegrityError:
    handle_exception()
```

Comment: import transaction should be : from django.db import transaction

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution using a [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly):

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def myview(request):
    # This code executes inside a transaction.
    model1.save()
    model2.save()
```