# Django Creation View Doesn't save any data

Tags: django

**My creation view redirect to blog main page well after creation but**

**i can't find any post's been created in the posts or admin page posts, can anyone help please**

**here is my view**

```
@login_required
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        snippet_form = SnippetForm(request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid() and snippet_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            snpt = snippet_form.save(commit=False)
            post.creator = request.user
            snpt.id = post.id
            post.save() and snpt.save()
            return redirect('blog:index')
    else:
        post_form = PostForm()
        snippet_form = SnippetForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_post.html', {'post': post_form, 'snpt': snippet_form})
```

**what's wrong in this view cause i been able to save new post from admin add new post but from client it doesn't save anything**

**Do I need to use model create() method here or what?**

**Any required snippet i will provide but the problem is in this snippet*
**any help is really appreciable**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

my Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    creator = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL...
    snippet = models.OneToOneField(Snippet,...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
post.save() and snpt.save()
```

should be:

```
post.save()
snpt.save()
```

I suspect you were thinking (by using the keyword `and`) that you want to ensure both models are saved at the same time, but you are actually asking Python to compare the return results of the two functions to see if they are both True; this is breaking your code (as save() returns None, only your first save() is running as Python will not even execute the second as there's no way they can both be True when the first has already returned Falsey).

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886690/how-do-i-save-multiple-django-models-in-a-single-transaction) useful in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

**in case anyone interested to know**

**Firstly**
As The relation between Post model and Snippet model is OneToOne, following line

```
snpt.id = post.id
```

need to be removed
would violates the unique pk constraint, if you changed the relation to foreign key that would add another instance of snippet with another pk

you can remove it or assign instead

```
post.snippet = snpt
```

**Secondly**
No need for commit=False in snpt_form as it already an instance of post_form and i didn't want to change anything else except the form fields

**Thirdly**
Either put

```
creator=request.user
```

instead of

```
instance=request.user
```

inside the post_form

or remove it and leave

```
post.creator = request.user
```

**forth**
Also as @bigkeefer mentioned but this is secondly arises after solving the main problem
the short circuit python precedence rule causing this line to fail

```
post.save() and snpt.save()
```

instead put

```
post.save()

snpt.save()
```